# React cannot access state from method

Tags: reactjs

I trying to access state from method in class (using react) but always when I executing method I have error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.icos.lastItem.id')
```

My code:

```
downloadIcos(fromId) {

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ icos: data })
      })
      .catch(console.log)
      
  }

    btnMoreOnClick(){
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.state))
  }
    
render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <button
            onClick={this.btnMoreOnClick}
            >
            More
            </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using this.setState, you have to have a arrow function

```
downloadIcos = (fromId) => {

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ icos: data })
      })
      .catch(console.log)
      
  }

btnMoreOnClick = (value) => {
return this.downloadIcos()
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <button
            onClick={this.btnMoreOnClick(this.state.icos.lastItem.id)}
            >
            More
            </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand. I just trying to call this.state from another method in this class but it always is undefined if is outside componentDidMount().

Comment: I'v edited my post to be more clear what I want do

Answer (score 0):

I'v finally fixed my code. All I need is to bind function btnMoreOnClick in constructor like below.

```
constructor(props) {
    this.btnMoreOnClick = this.btnMoreOnClick.bind(this)
  }
```